# Como adicionar um link do whatsapp em um contato

Tags: php, html5, whatsapp

Em minha datatable há uma coluna chamada contatos, quero adicionar um link para que quando o usuário clicar ali, pegue o número referente a variável e ligue com o link do whatsapp

```
<th><?= $properties['contato'] ?></th>
```

Como eu poderia fazer a mesma função em um modal

```
$('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><h4><b class="font-modal">Contato:</b> ${property.contato}</h4></div>`);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A API oficial do Whatsapp diz para usar:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=countrycode+phonenumber

logo para seu contexto ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<th><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?= $properties['contato'] ?>">Clique para ligar pelo Whatsapp</a></th>
```

lembrando que seu parâmetro `$properties['contato']` deve incluir o código do país de origem do número, no caso do Brasil é `55` um ex seria: 55DDD9NUMERO

Comment: Nessa ocasião, como eu colocaria por padrão o +55 ?

Comment: se todos os numeros forem exclusivamente de um mesmo país, vc pode colocar fixo, diretamente na construção do HTML da seguinte forma:
<th><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55<?= $properties['contato'] ?>">Clique para ligar pelo Whatsapp</a></th>

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta, na primeira ocasião até funciona, mas na segunda onde fica o meu modal ela não está funcionando.

Comment: No contexto do modal vc teria que ter um link:

`$('#view-property .modal-body').append('<div><h4><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${property.contato}"><b class="font-modal">Contato:</b> ${property.contato}</a></h4></div>');`